# Undefined Variables in Included Files

Tags: php

I recently installed a new version of XAMPP on my laptop. I moved over a web application from my desktop to my laptop and things wont work on here. I've found out that variables inside required and included files are being considered "undefined". Is there something different with the php.ini setup?

I have the following setup.

```
index.php
includes/config.php
includes/include.php
```

The `index.php` requires the `includes/include.php` which requires the `includes/config.php`. However the variables in the `config.php` are coming up as undefined in the `include.php`.

Ideas?

config.php

```
<?php

// WEBSITE INFO

    DEFINE ('WEBSITE_URL', 'http://localhost/xion/'); // Database name.
    DEFINE ('WEBSITE_MAIN', 'index.php'); // Website main page.


// MySQL

    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'xion'); // Database name.
    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'admin'); // Database user.
    DEFINE ('DB_PASS', 'admin'); // Database password.
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Database host.
    DEFINE ('DB_PFIX', 'xion_'); // Table prefix for multiple installs.

?>
```

include.php

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

// MySQL Config
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

// SmartyPHP Config
    require 'smartyphp/libs/Smarty.class.php';
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->caching = 0;
    $smarty->template_dir = 'templates/default';
    $smarty->compile_dir = 'templates_c'; 

// User Permissions
    session_start();

    if ( isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
        $logged_in = "TRUE";
        $smarty->assign('logged_in', $logged_in);

        foreach ( $_SESSION['user'] as $key => $value ) {
            $smarty->assign($key, $value);
        }

    } else {
        $logged_in = "FALSE";
        $smarty->assign('logged_in', $logged_in);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Need to see the file contents, but odds-on, you are attempting to use the variables out of scope.

Comment: What is the actual error message you have ? You talk about variable but all there is in config.php are constants

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Xion\includes\include.php on line 6

Comment: does that for each of the constants.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with your require's. If the files are all in the correct places, this should not happen. Please recheck that everything is the way you expect it to be.

Comment: Check your `config.php` on your laptop - it must have something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It could not possibly work as-is on your remote server. You need to read about php [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

- Your [current directory](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) is `./`
- You execute `./index.php`
- You include/require "include/include.php", which translates to `./include/include.php`

  Including a file does not change your working directory, you are still in `./`
- Then in that file you include "config.php", which translates to `./config.php` (which is wrong, since you want `./include/config.php`)

  Because the include of config.php failed, the constant are undefined

First; when using an important config files and/or a file which absolutely needs to be found for your application to be working, you should be using [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead of [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). If a require call fails, it will throw a php error. In your case, if you can't load your database credentials, you want to error out.

Second; when including config files and/or files that should not be included twice, you should use [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php). These call will make sure that, if the file has already been included before, it won't be included again. Two require of your config.php file would cause error because you would be trying to redefine existing constants.

To solve your problem, you have two solutions;

1. Add your ./include/ directory in the include_path

   index.php:

   ```
   <?php
   set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/includes/');
   include "include.php";
   ```

   include.php

   ```
   <?php
   require_once "config.php";
   ```
2. Add your config.php file using a relative path

   include.php

   ```
   <?php
   require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/config.php";
   ```

Please take the time to read the documentation link posted in this answer, to understand the difference between include, require, include_once, require_once, and what the include_path is.

Comment: It works fine on my desktop. I've always done it like this using relative paths. I just made a new directory and did a test and it worked too... May be a file permission thing? The files were copied over from a different computer.

Comment: @CoryNickerson: read my updated answer and apply what is said. Using require and checking your include_path and current directory would show you that you are indeed in the case I'm listing (or if not, it would help pinpoint where the problem lies). If anything, require should throw you a php error saying config.php can't be found.

Comment: Well when I change the file name it says the file cannot be found. However when I name the appropriate file (and the way I did it) it just displays the undefined variables and constants error message. Which makes it seems like it is loading the file but isn't reading from it properly? Not sure how to check/change file/folder permissions with XAMPP.